# Inequality on the norm of second-derivative of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

> Let $n\geq 3$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in \mathbb R$. Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} (x_{i+2}-2x_{i+1}+x_i)^2 \leq 16 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$

I'm at loss with this problem. I've tried all the standard inequalities I know, I've also considered expanding the square, to no avail.

I've also tried considering the LHS as the norm of the orthogonal projection of $x$ on a $n-2$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Use the inequality $(b-a)^2\leq 2(b^2+a^2)$, replacing first $b$ by $x_{i+2}-x_{i+1}$, $a$ by $(x_{i+1}-x_i)$, and then re-use this inequality with $b=x_{i+2}$, $a=x_{i+1}$, and also with $b=x_{i+1}$, $a=x_{i}$

Comment: @Kelenner I got it, feel free to post it as an answer

Comment: Done, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inequality $(b-a)^2\leq 2(b^2+a^2)$, replacing first $b$ by $x_{i+2}-x_{i+1}$, $a$ by $(x_{i+1}-x_i)$, and then re-use this inequality with $b=x_{i+2}$, $a=x_{i+1}$, and also with $b=x_{i+1}$, $a=x_{i}$